# jpa @joinColumns with a value from another joined column

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to implement entities of 3 tables

To represent;
Table A(fields A1, A2, A4)
Table B(fields B1, B2, B3)
Table C(fields C1, C3, C4)

(This is really how they implemented and it is not even the simplest join).

A(one) -> B (many) -- B(many) -> C(one)

But to be clear, B is not an intermediary table, it represents objects (just like A and C)

On my entity class B, I have implemented A -> B like this (which is working fine)

```
@JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "B1", referencedColumnName = "A1"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "B2", referencedColumnName = "A1"),
    })
private A a;
```

But the problem is B -> C join uses a field from table A too. What I want to implement is something like this

```
@JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "B1", referencedColumnName = "C1"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "B3", referencedColumnName = "C3"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "A4", referencedColumnName = "C4"),
            // or maybe like this
            // @JoinColumn(table = "A", name = "A4", referencedColumnName = "C4"),
    })
private C c;
```

But obviously, none of them worked. What is the implementation to join entity B to C using the value from table/entity A?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have both B's B1 and B2 reference A's A1 column, so hopefully that is a cut and paste error - What are the real foreign keys and what are the IDs for each table? This cannot work the way you seem to want it; B does NOT have a relationship to C, not really. It isn't clear if C1,C3, And C4 are part of a composite ID, but seems more like B has a OneToMany to C based on the C1,C3 partial keys, and you just want to filter out all but one C based on C4 values.

Comment: This is not the only columns of the tables but to be more clear, this is a legacy system that unfortunately no change is possible on the constraints. And this is the exact representation of the table constraints (the columns mentioned are primary keys, not the only ones of these tables)

Yes you are right there is no one to one connection from B to C on its own but that is how the system designed, B to C has a one to one relation with table A joined.

Technically, I can go with a one to many join to B to C but it is not the logical implementation of the system unfortunately.